# Need to count contents of cells to produce a knitting pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

So this needs a bit of detail:

n,X,X,X,n is in cells B5 to F5

I need to get the following output:

1n,3x,1n

for this particular row.

Now the n's and X's represent stitches in knitting with the "n" being the background color and the "x" being the front color.

There is an array of cells B5:F12 representing the rows and stitches, so each row will have a different arrangement of stitches or background color.

I need to avoid vba as this needs to be as stable as possible with the user being my Mum who is 90 years old :) and all she needs is a place to enter the name and the layout (which I have done) and a pattern list for each row (also sorted).

I have started to consider things like:

```
if(B5=C5,1&B5,"")
```

But given the n umber of combinations that becomes very long.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `H5`:

```
=BYROW(B5:F12,LAMBDA(x,LET(z,REDUCE(VSTACK(TAKE(x,,1),1),DROP(x,,1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=@TAKE(a,,-1),IF(COLUMNS(a)=1,VSTACK(b,TAKE(a,-1)+1),HSTACK(DROP(a,,-1),VSTACK(b,DROP(TAKE(a,,-1),1)+1))),HSTACK(a,VSTACK(b,1))))),TEXTJOIN(",",,DROP(z,1)&TAKE(z,1)))))
```

I'll see if I can golf the bytecount down a bit...

---

**EDIT:**

After a considerable amount of golfing (came down to 119), I came up with:

```
=BYROW(B5:F12,LAMBDA(x,MID(REDUCE("",x,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(RIGHT(a)=b,LEFT(a,LEN(a)-2)&1+LEFT(RIGHT(a,2)),a&",1")&b)),2,99)))
```

Though less dynamic than the 1st one, but possible due to the fact there are only <10 columns for each knitting pattern.

Comment: Holy smoke batman! It works - my version of excel complains about 1 function then applies it anyway. Now working through the functions - thanks for some new ones :)

Comment: I'm working with Excel already more than 25 years, and this formula contains not less than 8 (!) functions I've never heard of :-)

Comment: @SolarMike, I think I did a considerate amount of golfing to make it all much more user-friendly.

Answer (score 8):

If your mother doesn't have the latest Excel (with LAMBDA etc), here is an alternative to @JvdV's answer which only uses LET,SEQUENCE and FILTER.

It only accepts a single row, so you'd need to fill the formula down.

```
=LET(p,LOWER(B5:F5),c,COLUMNS(p),s,SEQUENCE(,c),
     a,IF(s=c,c,IF(INDEX(p,,s)<>INDEX(p,s+1),s,0)),
     b,FILTER(a,a>0),t,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(b)),
     n,IF(t=1,INDEX(b,,t),INDEX(b,,t)-INDEX(b,,t-1)),
     TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,n & INDEX(p,,b)))
```

I might add that it allows for adding more than one colour into the pattern ...

[image]

and with a bit of conditional formatting, the good lady can design her own multicolour patterns!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is just a start of a solution, but in cell "B6" you can put the formula:

```
=(IF(B5=A5,A6+1,1))
```

This will generate following list:

```
   B    C    D    E    F

5: n    x    x    x    n
6: 1    1    2    3    1
```

From there, you can try to get the Subtotals feature to work, based on the `Max` formula, ... (as I said, this is just a start).

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to spread the logic over multiple sheets, it's quite easy to come up with a way to do this. Consider a workbook with three sheets:

Pattern
[image]

EqualPrevCol, where each cell of Pattern is checked for equality against the previous column of the same row.
[image]

The formula for cell `EqualPrevCol!D3` is:

```
=Pattern!D3=Pattern!C3
```

And finally PatternResult, where most of the logic resides:
[image]

Consider one row of `EqualPrevCol`:
At every `FALSE` column, we want to know *how many* columns until the next `FALSE`. To do this, we want to find the next exact `MATCH` for `D3` in the rest of the row:

```
=MATCH(EqualPrevCol!D3, EqualPrevCol!E3:$H3, 0)
```

If no match is found, that means the rest of the row is all `TRUE`. In this situation, we want to return the length of the rest of the row plus this current cell.

```
=IFNA(MATCH(...), COLUMNS(D3:$H3))
```

And finally, we append this to the current character:

```
=IFNA(...) & Pattern!D3
```

Also, if the `7` row at this column is `TRUE`, we want to keep this blank:

```
=IF(EqualPrevCol!D3, "", IFNA(...) & ...)
```

The full formula of cell `PatternResult!D3` is:

```
=IF(EqualPrevCol!D3, "", IFNA(MATCH(EqualPrevCol!D3, EqualPrevCol!E3:$H3, 0), COLUMNS(D3:$H3)) & Pattern!D3)
```

Finally, the pattern is condensed to the `Pattern` sheet. The `Pattern!B3` cell contains:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, PatternResult!D3:$H3)
```

To scale this up, you simply need to change all occurrences of `$H` in the formulas (this was a reference to the last column) and re-fill the cells on the latter two sheets.